# c++ serialization of a structure

Tags: c++, object, serialization

While compiling this simple code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class Example
{
    public:
        char  charo;
        int   into;
};

int main()
{
    Example one,two;

    one.charo = 'X'; one.into = 2;

    //WRITING
    ofstream file;
    file.open("my.prx", ios_base::binary);
    if(file.good()) file.write((char*)&one, sizeof(Example));
    else cout << "ERROR WHILE OPENING FILE" << endl;
    file.close();

    //READING
    file.open("my.prx", ios_base::binary);
    if(file.good())
    file.read((char*)&two, sizeof(Example));
    else cout << "ERROR WHILE OPENING FILE" << endl;
    file.close();

    //PRINTING
    cout << "CHAR: " << two.charo << endl;
    cout << "INT: " << two.into << endl;

}
```

I get this error message:

> g++ -o test1 main.c main.c: In function ‘int main()’: main.c:43:7:
>   error: ‘std::ofstream’ has no member named ‘read’
>   file.read((char*)&two, sizeof(Example));

How can I solve it?
My next step will be to make a more complicated object to save:

```
Class Memory{
    t_monitor monitors[MAX_MONITORS];
    t_status status[MAX_STATUS]; 
    t_observer observers[MAX_OBSERVERS];
    Var * first_var;
    int tot_observers;
    int tot_status;
    int tot_monitors;   
};
```

As you can see there is also a list...

Comment: I'd use an existing solution such as [boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) instead of reinventing the wheel ...

Comment: The `o` in `ofstream` stands for *output*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ifstream` to read `ostream` is used for output.

You can do something like this

```
std::ifstream fileRead( "my.prx",std::ifstream::binary );
if(fileRead)
fileRead.read((char*)&two, sizeof(Example));
else cout << "ERROR WHILE OPENING FILE" << endl;
fileRead.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

`ofstream` is an ***output file stream***. It's used for output, and can't "read".

Use `fstream` instead.

Answer (score 1):

An `[ofstream][1]` is output only.  One readable way is to use the variables `ofstream ofile` and `ifstream ifile`.   This way the usage is clear from the declaration and the name.   If the code grows, this might be helpful.

Another way would be to use the dual-use `fstream`, but this can make certain operations ambiguous.

Of course, these days, you're probably better off using some sort of serialization library.   First, preferring the one that your company or group already uses, and then, if that one is inadequate, picking a modern lib like [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html) or, my fave, [Cereal](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/quickstart.html).

Comment: Do you have any example where it is shown how to use boost for serialiaze a class similar to mine Memory (with array and list)?